# No Linker Options in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, properties, visual-studio-2015

I reset my notebook and new installed my Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10 Pro N. But I have a problem with my projects.

While the Properties where I can set Libraries and Linker work well on my PC on my Notebook these Options aren´t available for me. When I right-click on the Project -> Properties I get the following window:

[image]

How can I get back the regular options in the Project Properties?

Comment: Did you install the C++ development tools? I believe they are optional.

Comment: Yes, I've chosen the whole visual c++ part while installation.

Comment: Well, something went *very* wrong when you installed VS2015 on your laptop.  This is usually caused by having it installed before, like a beta or trial edition, and not properly uninstalling it.  So the installer thinks that a sub-component is present and it actually isn't.  Running the installer with the /uninstall /force command line options tends to repair the registry damage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to reinstall Windows 10 (without N) and Visual Studio.

Now everthing works again but no idea where the problem came from.